# Java refreshing second form

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have two forms. First one is to decide numbers of button by using jslider. Second form is to display jbuttons according to jslider value. When i click jbutton2, the second form shows and display buttons. It is working perfectly. However, I want to create jbutton on the second form without clicking jbutton2 in the first form. 
Instead, when I change jslider, it should create jbuttons on the second form at the run time and once i change jslider it should create that amount of button again on the second form and refreshing  the second form button numbers according to jslider value. 
I have tried revalidate();, repaint(); but they do not work, they dont refresh the second form.

So, How can I refresh second form when the jslider ,that is on the first form, changes ? Please help.....

Edit:I am using default Jframe of netbeans....

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
public class NewJFrame7 extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame7
     */
    public NewJFrame7() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSlider1.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
        jSlider1.setMaximum(20);
        jSlider1.setMinimum(1);
        jSlider1.setPaintLabels(true);
        jSlider1.setPaintTicks(true);
        jSlider1.setToolTipText("");
        jSlider1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSlider1StateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 295, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(273, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(262, 262, 262)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addContainerGap(262, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(168, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(138, 138, 138)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addContainerGap(139, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:



    }                                     

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        form2 = true;
        new NewJFrame8().setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame7().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**2.form**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class NewJFrame8 extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame8
     */
    public NewJFrame8() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(371, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(19, 19, 19))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(242, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame8.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame8.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame8.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame8.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame8().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: BTW - the 2nd `JFrame` should probably be a `JDialog`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
  1) missing 2 closing `}` 
2) No imports 
3) `initComponents()` does not exist.
4) No `jSlider1` or `jPanel1` declared. ... 
General advice:  a) Where did you get those class and variable names?  Call them something sensible, for pity's sake.  b) Don't extend frame (or dialog, for that matter).

Comment: sorry for missing }, i fixed them. I am using default Jframe of netbeans, so the rest of the code is default code of netbeans.....

Comment: For Andrew, I need jframe for further process. Do you think it is better to use jdialog for displaying  buttons on it.

Comment: *"so the rest of the code is default code of netbeans"* I very much doubt that, since `jPanel1` is still not declared.  What appears above will not **compile** let alone display a run-time problem.  Also, Netbeans will generally indent code in a logical and consistent manner, whereas that code appears to have been indented by your dog.  So long story short.  Please stop wasting your time, and more importantly *mine,* by posting such incomprehensible, uncompileable code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SliderExample
{
    private JSlider slider;

    private static final int MIN_BUTTONS = 2;
    private static final int SOME_BUTTONS = 4;  
    private static final int MAX_BUTTONS = 6;

    private JButton[] buttonArray;
    private ActionListener actionButton = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();
            System.out.println(button.getText());
        }
    };

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        ButtonPanel bp = new ButtonPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSlider Example : ");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, MIN_BUTTONS, MAX_BUTTONS
                                                            , SOME_BUTTONS);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce)
            {
                int value = (int) slider.getValue();
                ButtonPanel.panel.removeAll();
                buttonArray = new JButton[value];
                for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                {
                    buttonArray[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
                    buttonArray[i].addActionListener(actionButton);
                    ButtonPanel.panel.add(buttonArray[i]);
                }
                ButtonPanel.panel.revalidate();
                ButtonPanel.panel.repaint();
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(slider);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new SliderExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class ButtonPanel extends JFrame
{
    public static JPanel panel;

    public ButtonPanel()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);       
    }
}
```

For your statement `this.buttonArray[i].addActionListener(this);`, the reason as to why this is not working, is because, you are inside the object of `anonymous class` `new ChangeListener()`, which doesn't have anything named `buttonArray[i]` inside itself, it's the Instance Variable of `SliderExample` class, so either place an object of `SliderExample` class or if you are referring to your code, then use the `Object` of the class which initializes the array like inside inside `NewFrame8` you had written `JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[120];`, so use `NewFrame8`'s object instead of `this` to refer to the `buttonArray[i]` thingy.

Comment: @CoKoder : Is this what you asking for ? Here don't use this line `new NewJFrame8().checkincomingdata();`, this is causing the issue for you, a new object everytime the value changes. Instead make this method `static` and call it by `class Name`.

Comment: I need to add  "this.buttonArray[i].addActionListener(this); " after    "ButtonPanel.panel.add(buttonArray[i]);" But it says "cannot find symbol". How can I add this line inside of slider changelistener ?

Comment: @CoKoder : Sorry for the delay in replay, that was night time when you send that message. Had had improved the code and added some lines of text at the end, have a look. You cannot use `this`, since `this` is referring to the `ChangeListener` class, which doesn't have anything like `buttonArray[i]`, this variable belongs to their respective classes, like `SliderExample` for my case and `NewFrame8` in your case. So use the objects of these classes to refer to this variable, instead of using this :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are great men !!!, One more question, How to decide location of jslider on the jframe ? cause, it shows up arbitrary location on the jframe

Comment: @CoKoder : For that your `LayoutManager` can help you, as to where you want to place it, on the `JFrame`, like you can set your `JSlider` as `slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, MIN_BUTTONS, MAX_BUTTONS, SOME_BUTTONS);` and then you can place it at `frameObject.add(slider, BorderLayout.LINE_START);`, that will add it to the left side of the `JFrame`

Answer (score 3):

One layout constraint (`BorderLayout.CENTER`) to place them, and one component to appear therein.  (With apologies to Tolkien.)

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? BorderLayout.CENTER is for centralize the buttons on the screen.

Comment: Post an SSCCE & I will comment further.  Anything beyond that is speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Do check this sample Program, is this what you need. `revalidate()` and `repaint()` is what works here for this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SliderExample
{
    private JSlider slider;

    private static final int MIN_BUTTONS = 2;
    private static final int SOME_BUTTONS = 4;  
    private static final int MAX_BUTTONS = 6;

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        ButtonPanel bp = new ButtonPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSlider Example : ");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, MIN_BUTTONS, MAX_BUTTONS
                                                            , SOME_BUTTONS);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce)
            {
                int value = (int) slider.getValue();
                ButtonPanel.panel.removeAll();
                for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                {
                    ButtonPanel.panel.add(new JButton("JButton " + i));
                }
                ButtonPanel.panel.revalidate();
                ButtonPanel.panel.repaint();
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(slider);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new SliderExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class ButtonPanel extends JFrame
{
    public static JPanel panel;

    public ButtonPanel()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);       
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I need to use "buttonArray[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i + 1));" for further process of my program. Could you adopt your code for using buttonarray ?  thanks....

Comment: @CoKoder : Please give me 10 mins or so :-)

Comment: @CoKoder : See what I did, I made the `JPanel` static on the other class, so that I can access it as and when needed. What you showed me in that edit, it seems to me as if you are initiating your `JFrame` again and again, so many new instances are being created. Instead use my approach, simply use `removeAll()` on your `JPanel` and add new things on it.

Comment: I need to add "this.buttonArray[i].addActionListener(this); " after "ButtonPanel.panel.add(buttonArray[i]);" But it says "cannot find symbol". How can I add that line in the slider changelistener ? please help.....